# When and how is the .NET managed heap getting swapped?

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, heap-memory, swap

My small stress test, which allocates random length arrays (100..200MB each) in a loop, shows different behaviour on a 64 bit Win7 machine and on a 32 bit XP (in a VM). Both systems first normally allocate as much arrays as will fit into the LOH. Then the LOH gets bigger and bigger until the virtual address space available is filled up. Expected behaviour so far. But than - on further requests - both behave differently:

While on Win7 an OutOfMemoryException (OOM) is thrown, on XP it seems, the heap gets increased and even swapped to disk - at least no OOM is thrown. (Dont know, if this may have to do with XP running in a virtual box.)

Question: 
How does the runtime (or the OS?) decide, whether for managed memory allocation requests, if it is too large to get allocated, a OOM is generated or the large object heap is getting increased - eventually even swapped to disk? 
If it is swapped, when does an OOM occour than?

IMO this question is important to all production environments, potentially dealing with larger datasets. Somehow it feels more "safe" to know, the system would rather slow down dramatically in such situations (by swapping) than simply throwing an OOM. At least, it should somehow be deterministically, right?

@Edit: the app is a 32 bit application, therefore running in 32 bit mode on Win 7.

Comment: "until the physical address space" don't you mean the virtual address space of that process?

Comment: And is your program set to AnyCPU or to 32BitOnly? Out of memories in a 64 bit program should not happen easily. I'd expect the computer to grind to halt due to excessive swapping long before that.

Comment: you are right: "virtual address space" was meant. And yes, the prog compiles to a 32 bit application, running WOW on Win7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal rules apply, a managed process is not treated differently by the Windows memory manager.  The ultimate source for chunks of memory is the Windows memory manager.  If it cannot find a hole in the virtual memory address space to fit the requested memory allocation then it fails the VirtualAlloc() call and the CLR generates OOM.

Same for swapping behavior, if pages in RAM are needed to map pages of other processes or even pages of the same process then they'll get swapped out.  This is not otherwise associated with OOM.

You cannot assume it will work exactly the same on XP as it does on Win7 x64.  Getting OOM on x64 when you build your program targeting AnyCPU is quite unusual, a 64-bit operating system has a very large virtual memory address space.  The upper limit is set by the maximum size of the paging file.  A 32-bit program will run in the WOW emulation layer, it can have a 4 GB address space if you set the LARGEADDRESSAWARE option bit with Editbin.exe.

You can use SysInteral's VMMap utility to see how the address space of your process is carved up.

Comment: "If it cannot find a hole in the virtual memory address space to fit the requested memory allocation then it fails the HeapAlloc() call and the CLR generates OOM." - but why the hack is it not paging than? At least it should, if the virtual space is not fully used up yet, but no other RAM could be found?

Comment: Two *very* different things.  Paging occurs when *physical* memory space needs to be found.  RAM.  Memory allocations occur in *virtual* memory.  A 32-bit process has 2 gigabytes of it, no matter how much RAM is installed.  The sum of all virtual memory allocated by all processes is only limited by the paging file, not RAM.

Comment: So the 2GB (some TB on 64bit) are only theoretical limits? Memory manager swaps until the size of the pagefile *part* which is reserved for the process was filled up? And if that part even fits in RAM, it doesn't even swap at all? This would answer the question

Comment: Only the last comment is accurate.  I'd recommend "Windows Internals" for more insight.

Comment: the last sentense should read: "And if the virtual memory for the process completely fits in RAM, it doesn't even swap at all?"

Comment: @Hans - Does that mean if a machine has 32GB of physical ram the page file needs to be configured to be able to grow to at least 32GB in order to use the full 32GB of physical ram?

Comment: Well, a significant chunk of it is going to be used by the file system cache.  But, yes, if you'd want to be able to run a process that needs 32GB or more then you need that much paging file.  The default setup is 1.5 times RAM size, allowing that to grow.  For paging file size tuning, ask questions at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant; regarding the part about "LARGEADDRESSAWARE", 32-bit process has virtual memory of 4GB, 2gb for user-space, and 2gb mapped to kernel. If you set LAA, it means the 32-bit process will havr 3gb for user-space, and 1gb for kernel. For original author; google for terms PAE, Large address extensions, AWE - they are very interesting ;)

Comment: No, those assumptions are only valid for a 32-bit operating system.  The /3GB boot option has been itself irrelevant for quite a while already, even on a 32-bit OS.